# Unable to compile Magento 2 theme

Tags: magento, less, command-line-interface, magento2

I am attempting to compile a Magento theme which uses Magento/blank as the parent, every I attempt this I am presented with the following error

```
[fsvuphkpwz]:public_html$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_AU

Deploy using quick strategy
frontend/Magento/blank/en_AU            2163/2163           ============================ 100% %  1 sec               
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_AU         2104/2104           ============================ 100% %  1 sec               
frontend/Magento/blank/en_AU            2163/2163           ============================ 100% %  1 sec               
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_AU         2104/2104           ============================ 100% %  1 sec               
frontend/Magento/luma/en_AU             2179/2179           ============================ 100% %  1 sec               
frontend/GladiatorFitness/Gladiator/en_AU 2069/2201           ==========================>- 94% %   5 secs
Compilation from source: /mnt/data/home/######/fsvuphkpwz/public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
error evaluating function `darken` The first argument to darken must be a color index: 2570 in _typography.less in _resets.less in _reset.less


  [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]                                                                                                                                                        
  Cannot read contents from file "/mnt/data/home/#####/fsvuphkpwz/public_html/pub/static/frontend/GladiatorFitness/Gladiator/en_AU/css/styles-l.css" Warning!file_get_contents(/mnt/da  
  ta/home/#####/fsvuphkpwz/public_html/pub/static/frontend/GladiatorFitness/Gladiator/en_AU/css/styles-l.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

All I have in _theme.less is as per below

```
//  Color nesting
@page__background-color: "#fff";
@sidebar__background-color: @color-gray40;
@primary__color: @color-gray80;
@border-color__base: @color-gray76;

@link__color: @color-gray56;
@link__hover__color: @color-gray60;

//  Buttons
@button__color: @color-gray20;
@button__background: @color-gray80;
@button__border: 1px solid @border-color__base;

//  Primary button
@button-primary__background: "#f15429";
@button-primary__border: none;
@button-primary__color: @color-white;
@button-primary__hover__background: "#f15429";
@button-primary__hover__border: none;
@button-primary__hover__color: @color-white;

//  Navigation
@navigation-level0-item__color: @color-gray80;
@submenu-item__color: @color-gray80;

@navigation__background: @color-gray40;
@navigation-desktop-level0-item__color: @color-gray80;
@navigation-desktop-level0-item__hover__color: @color-gray34;
@navigation-desktop-level0-item__active__color: @navigation-desktop-level0-item__color;

//  Tabs
@tab-control__background-color: @page__background-color;

//  Forms
@form-element-input__background: @color-gray89;
@form-element-input-placeholder__color: @color-gray60;

//  Header icons
@header-icons-color: @color-gray89;
@header-icons-color-hover: @color-gray60;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message from the compilation says

```
Compilation from source: 

public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less
error evaluating function `darken` 
The first argument to darken must be a color index: 
    2570 in _typography.less in _resets.less in _reset.less
```

So it sounds like there's stock magento code that calls the LessCSS darken function/subroutine/etc? (I'm not sure what the LessCSS terminology is).  However, there's a problem with the argument -- it's not a valid LessCSS color index.

Here's an example of darken being called.

```
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/css/source/lib/variables/_typography.less
80:@border-color__base: darken(@page__background-color, 18%);
```

That's a call to darken whose first argument is `@page__background-color`.

So, there's a call to darken in your system that has a first argument whose value isn't "a valid LessCSS color index". So, something you've changed -- (a call to darken you've added yourself? Changing the value of a variable like `@page__background-color` to something that's not a valid color index?  Accidentally removing a variable somewhere?) -- has made it so your system tries to call `darken` with an invalid value.

Based on what you've posted, my first guess would be this

```
@page__background-color: "#fff";
```

needs to be this

```
@page__background-color: #ffffff;
```

But that's just a first guess.

Hope that helps, and good luck.

Comment: this has helped remove one a error an introduced a new one. this is very weird as i have followed the magento documents to extend their base theme